# How to set the height of a horizontalListView to be wrap_content?

Tags: android, android-layout

### Background

Android doesn't have a horizontalListView, so I used [this one](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android) ([here's a direct link](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android/blob/master/devsmartlib/src/com/devsmart/android/ui/HorizontalListView.java)).

### The problem

I need to set the height of the horizontalListView to be the same as of the items within it, and for some reason something that worked fine for the normal listView doesn't work here- wrap_content makes the view take the whole height, yet the items take the minimal height they need. Both heights should be the same.

So, for example, this code works:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0px"
android:background="#ff00ff00"
android:text="tt2" android:layout_weight="1"
android:textSize="30dp" />


<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffff0000"
android:text="tt"
android:textSize="30dp" />
```

But if I use the HorizontalListView as the bottom view, it takes the whole area. It also doesn't work if I use RelativeLayout.

Not only that, but using the layoutParams of each item to have a specific height (inside the getView() method) also doesn't change a thing, and they keep taking the minimal height they need (even if I set them to be 2 times larger).

### Question

Is there any fix for this class that makes it possible to use it the same way we use the ListView ?

Comment: I have found that children sometimes determine the parent's dimensions if the parent is set to wrap content. Change the child height parameters and see if that works

Comment: that's what i've already written i've tried- set the layoutParams of the children on the getView method. However, maybe it doesn't make much sense since the listView can have tons of views (though it re-uses old ones). The question is , why it can't work like any other view and take the space i let it have, and why can't it use the gravity too.